# Expand a line in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform, html-table

Using the following example, a table that pulls all of the items in Parse for its particular column (I.e. if there is 20 subjects in parse, than 20 subjects would be displayed).
http://jsfiddle.net/richf/sKLxE/

Below is the code for it:

Javascript:

```
//message
  var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Message"); 
    var query = new Parse.Query(Message);
        query.descending("createdAt");         
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
    //alert("Successfully retrieved " );
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      (function($) {
   $('#messages-table').append('<tr><td>' + object.get('currentDate') + '</td><td>' +  object.get('Subject') + '</td><td>' + object.get('Message') + '</td></tr>');
})(jQuery);

      //alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
    }
    },
    error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
```

HTML

```
<table id="messages-table">
<tr>     
<th>
<h1>Date</h1></th>


 <th>
<h1>Subject</h1></th>



  <th><h1>Message</h1></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the following is making each line clickable, where when someone clicks on a line then the message from the “message” column in parse is retrieved, and displayed right below the line click, and once that line is click again, that message is hidden.

This is a massive dilemma I am having, I have spent quite some time trying to resolve it.

If you need any clarification, let me know.

Comment: Similar popup functionality http://jsfiddle.net/SRw67/

Comment: thanks for your response, but not exactly a popup but more it would be displayed within the document (just push the line below down to create space to display the item)

Comment: Can you provide some data to play with for messages and table display?

Comment: thanks for your response. Below is a good example, the only I a missing is that making it that when that line is click a message is shown, we can start by just displaying a text that says it works, and from there I can see how I can pull the message data directly from parse and where its related to subject and date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the rows... and add your additional data as a hidden table row.

```
  $('#results-table').append('<tr class="results-row"><td>' + object.get('playerName') + '</td><td>' + object.get('score') + '</td></tr><tr class="xtra"><td colspan="2">INSERT MESSAGE HERE</td></tr>');
```

(Note extra table row added above)

CSS: `.xtra {display: none;}`

Then you can easily toggle that extra row:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.results-row', function () {
  $(this).next('.xtra').toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sKLxE/34/)</kbd>

Comment: thank you very much scott. It is what I was looking for. One quick question, lets see I wanted to replace INSERT MESSAGE HERE with object.get('score'), i tried to do so in the demo, but that wouldn't work

Comment: @Jon works fine here.... http://jsfiddle.net/sKLxE/40/ ... you must have an error in the demo.

Comment: If you don't mind I would just like to ask you a quick revision. I have added a button called "delete", where that button appears once a user has click a line (along with the message), I am having a major issue but I would want that entire line  (along with its  message, subject, etc) to be deleted once the user clicks on the delete button below is the update http://jsfiddle.net/sKLxE/84/ i would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

First add some indicator for the element which on click will have some action.
For example:

```
$('#results-table').append('<tr><td class="player">'
```

Then add an event listener as below:

```
$(document).on('click' , 'td.player', function () {
  alert("Clicked on" + $(this).hmtl());
});
```